# Set userProvider dynamically at runtime for JAAS logins to LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, jaas

I have a J2SE application that is setup correctly to handle user authentication with an LDAP server. However, the URL is hard-coded in the config file.

e.g. `userProvider="ldaps://host.domain.com:3269/DC=domain,DC=com"`

I would like to move toward dynamically finding an LDAP server by querying DNS SRV records.

Once I find an LDAP server, how do I set the JAAS userProvider property dynamically at runtime without specifying it in the config file? All the examples I see only show the URL coming from the config file. The JavaDocs aren't too clear on this question.

Comment: 'userProvider' is not an LDAP parameter. It is a parameter of your application. Where you set it is of no concern to Java.

Comment: However, it is a parameter for JAAS correct? Will JAAS accept the userProvider property in any other way than an external config file? (set a System variable, use a setter function somewhere...)

Comment: 1. No, it's a parameter to a specific JAAS LoginModule. 2. No, you have to write a JAAS config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to EJP, I got on the right track. Fortunately, System variables can be interpolated in the config file. [(Reference)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html)

Therefore, I can do something like this in the config file:

```
userProvider="ldaps://${ldap.host}/DC=domain,DC=com"
```

In my Java code, I set the system property "ldap.host":

```
System.setProperty("ldap.host","host.domain.com:3269");
```